# Connecting to elasticsearch cluster in NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Let's assume I have several elasticsearch machines in a cluster: 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3

Any of the machines can go down. It doesn't look like NEST supports providing a range of IPs to try to connect.

So how do I make sure I connect to any of the available machines from Nest? Just try to open connection to one, if TryConnect didn't work, try another?

Answer (score 6):

You can run a local ES instance at your application server (eg your web server) and config it to work as a load balancer:

- Set `node.client: true` (or `node.master: false` and `node.data: false`) for this local ES config to make it a load balancer. This mean ES will not become master nor contains data
- Config it to join the cluster (your 3 nodes don't need to know this ES)
- Config NEST to use local ES as your search server

Then this ES become a part of your cluster, and will distribute your requests to suitable nodes

If you don't want "load balancer", then you have to manually checking on client side to determine which node is alive.

Comment: That's a cool idea! Do you think there would be a lot of overhead on the webserver if I do this vs trying to connect to server directly?

Comment: Anybody knows if this is a method approved by the authors of NEST?

Comment: @Sumrak this will consume some memory on webserver because the client node is responsible for gathering the responses of the data nodes and for sorting among others. In summary, there'll be no "a lot of overhead"

Comment: @lasseschou this method is related to ES architecture, not NEST. NEST is just a library to connect to a node and querying/indexing data. Node here can be any node within ES cluster

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a small set of nodes, you can use a [StaticConnectionPool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/connection-pooling.html#static-connection-pool):

```
var uri1 = new Uri("192.168.1.1");
var uri2 = new Uri("192.168.1.2");
var uri3 = new Uri("192.168.1.3");
var uris = new List<Uri> { uri1, uri2, uri3 };
var connectionPool = new StaticConnectionPool(uris);
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool); // <-- need to be reused
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

An important point to keep in mind is to reuse the same `ConnectionSetting` when creating a new elastic client, since elasticsearch cache is per `ConnectionSetting`. [See this GitHub post](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2260):

> ...In any case its important to share the same ConnectionSettings
>   instance across any elastic client you instantiate. ElasticClient can
>   be a singleton or not as long as each instance shares the same
>   ConnectionSettings instance.
>
> All of our caches are per ConnectionSettings, this includes
>   serialization caches.
>
> Also a single ConnectionSettings holds a single IConnectionPool and
>   IConnection something you definitely want to reuse across requests.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up one of the nodes as a load balancer. Meaning that the URL your are calling should allways be up.

Though if you increase the number of replicas you can call any of the nodes by URL and still access the same data. ElasticSearch does not care which one you access while in a cluster. So you could build your own range of ips in your application.

Comment: What if the acting "load balancer" goes down? It's in the cloud, so cloud can decide to restart any of the machines without any warning.

Comment: With url, I want to avoid exposing public url and keep everything on internal virtual network. Would like to avoid setting up DNS server. So, I can have for example .1-.3 machines. I'm guaranteed that 2 of the 3 are up. But I don't know which and when any of them go down. To me the client connection lib needs to handle this (btw, I'm pretty sure Java client can work with this).

Comment: As you say, I have not seen this kind of functionality in the connection lib of NEST. It would be a nice feature for sure. If not in the cloud, you do not have to make the URL public. Just bind it internally on the servers. But in your case I think you will manually have to build something that can do what you want. Sorry I couldn't help more :)